# is there any way to find notification request content in didFinishedlaunch with options methods?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I know we can get aps dictionary in this method like this

```
   if let notify = launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? [String : Any]{

    if let apsData = userInfo["aps"] as? [String : Any] {

        print(aps1)

      }

    }
```